# 'rootNavigator: true' causes exception when using pushNamed

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm fairly new to Flutter...

I have a home page which uses a BottomNavBar. I'm trying to get a second page to slide in over the first and cover up the BottomNavBar. I've been able to get the functionality I need by using:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => const SecondPage(),
  ),
);
```

However, we are trying to use named routes throughout our app. I can successfully navigate to the second page using:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, SecondPage.routeName);
```

This works but still displays the BottomNavBar.

I get the same result when I use:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: false)
        .pushNamed(SecondPage.routeName);
```

However, when I use:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
        .pushNamed(SecondPage.routeName);
```

I get the following exception:

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/comments", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate
this route.
Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:

1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
   Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.)

For more context, we are using `onGenerateRoute` in our `Navigator`:

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    ...
    case SecondPage.routeName:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => const SecondPage(),
      );
```

I'm at a loss as to why those other cases work as expected but not the one I need. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that... I'm keeping this incase this helps others.

I learned a ton by figuring this out. Using rootNavigator is not the right approach here. When using named routes, if `rootNavigator: true` then the navigation hierarchy won't work as expected.

The correct solution was to handle the state of the bottom nav instead. This thread helped a ton: https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/rxp44b/full_screen_page_inside_nested_navigation_with_a/